# Responsive height for single page website

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm trying to understand how to build a single-page website layout, made of a series of pages, each occupying the whole viewport:

```
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
```

For example, I really like layouts like the one in this bootstrap template:

http://startbootstrap.com/templates/freelancer/

Actually, the problem with it, is the height of each page: while it's acceptable for most resolutions, I wanna be sure that each page is exactly the same width and height the viewport has.

I don't mind using javascript, in fact, I suspect that's impossible to achieve without some kind of JS (maybe "listening" to resize events, too) adjusting page-divs height.

Obviously, an only-css solution would be better. Suggestions?

Comment: Are you saying you want to resize each page's content so that no matter what size the viewport, you always see a **full** page?

Comment: Are you looking for `vh`? http://caniuse.com/#search=vh

Comment: not just one page (as the example "cover" bootstrap template)... all pages should have the same size the window has. I saw a lot of responsive single-pages websites behaving like that: you never see the "breaking line" between pages

Comment: @Bart ... seems buggy :(

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=one+page+website+full+height+sections&gws_rd=ssl

Comment: http://jsbin.com/varemo/1

Comment: @Christina maybe the jsbin you posted is what I'm looking for. What's the 'resize' event and overall compatibility for this solution however? Thank you a lot!

Comment: The resize event works well, I use it all the time and tested it on many, many devices and browsers. The only time this stuff is messed is IE8, I don't know if it will work on that. The rest of it is common enough css, it's html5 so it also won't work on IE8 without the shiv. I always use modernizer and create fallbacks, so if the height is not 100% in ie8 it is whatever it is. Feel free to post it as an answer and I'll vote you up. I'm going to make some dinner.

Comment: The resize is in the jQuery panel, see it in the http://jsbin.com/varemo/1/edit it's common and used a lot.

Comment: thank you @Christina! please, post it as answer, I'll accept it immediately!

Comment: @FabioB. Why don't you do like this: You make your body (lets say) with a height of `100 * number of pages you wish %`. Then, on each page, you put the height as `100 / number of pages you wish %`. For 5 pages, you put your body with `height: 500%` and for each page you use `height:20%`. If you want 2 pages, you put `height: 200%` on your body and `height: 50%` on each page.

Comment: it won't allow resizing

Comment: @FabioB. Well, I tried this way, and I noticed the formula isn't correct. The results aren't reliable. Check this:  http://jsfiddle.net/tsgqnjfr/1/ (5 pages) and this: http://jsfiddle.net/672fdmc4/1/ (2 pages). But when you make a container div with the `height:100*number of pages%` and the body and html with `height:100%`, **IT WORKS** too beautifully!  Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/672fdmc4/2/ (2 pages) and here: http://jsfiddle.net/tsgqnjfr/2/ (5 pages). I will post as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make it work, you can use something like giving `height:100%;width:100%` to the body and html.

Then you create a container div and give it `height: 100 * <number of pages> %`.

On each page, you give them `height: 100 / <number of pages> %`.

Since this is percent-based, it will work in **ANY** resolution.

Here is the complete html+css:

```html
<html>
    <head>
      <style type='text/css'>
        html,body{height:100% !important;width:100% !important; margin:0px; padding:0px;}

        .container {height: 500% !important; width: 100% !important;}

        .page {height:20% !important; width:100% !important;}
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="page1" class="page">
                page1
            </div>
            <div id="page2" class="page">
                page2
            </div>
            <div id="page3" class="page">
                page3
            </div>
            <div id="page4" class="page">
                page4
            </div>
            <div id="page5" class="page">
                page5
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can check it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/tsgqnjfr/2/ (5 pages) and here: http://jsfiddle.net/672fdmc4/2/ (2 pages)

---

If you can't make a container div, and have to use straight into the body, you can make like this:

You set the body and html with `height: 150%` for 2 pages and `height: 50*<number of pages>+1 %`

Then you set each page with `height: 100/<number of pages>%`.

Like in here:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style type='text/css'>
            html,body{height:250% !important;width:100% !important; margin:0px; padding:0px;}

            .page {height:20% !important; width:100% !important;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="page1" class="page">
            page1
        </div>
        <div id="page2" class="page">
            page2
        </div>
        <div id="page3" class="page">
            page3
        </div>
        <div id="page4" class="page">
            page4
        </div>
        <div id="page5" class="page">
            page5
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can check here: http://jsfiddle.net/tsgqnjfr/1/ (5 pages) and here: http://jsfiddle.net/672fdmc4/1/ (2 pages)

**Notice:** This method is **UNRELIABLE** and gives "slightly" wrong heights.

To try to counter-act this, you can try to use the other method and set different heights for each, using the `body` as the container `div`.

**Update**

Mixing the 2 methods, actually **WORKS** reliably.

Like this:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style type='text/css'>
            html{height:100% !important;width:100% !important; margin:0px; padding:0px;}

            body{height:500% !important;width:100% !important; margin:0px; padding:0px;}

            .page {height:20% !important; width:100% !important;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="page1" class="page">
            page1
        </div>
        <div id="page2" class="page">
            page2
        </div>
        <div id="page3" class="page">
            page3
        </div>
        <div id="page4" class="page">
            page4
        </div>
        <div id="page5" class="page">
            page5
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

To check them in action: http://jsfiddle.net/mgezx5f3/1/ (5 pages) and here: http://jsfiddle.net/x2kz3od7/ (2 pages).

---

**Notice:** If you are worried about compatibility, you can use these methods in **EVERY BROWSER** that supports css, even in [Quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) on IE!

As long as it uses css, this method will work (reliability is described in each method).

Answer (score 3):

I recently wanted to do the same thing and discovered the CSS viewport units. Older browsers will not support these and IE has some slight differences but this might be what you are looking for:

-> http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values/#viewport-relative-lengths

-> http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

So if you wanted to make a div be the same size as the viewport then you could do something like this:

HTML: `<div id="myDiv"></div>`

CSS: `#myDiv { width: 100vw; height: 100vh }`

Comment: Using `height: 100vh` is the right answer today. Back in the day, that CSS unit was very new. Now-a-days, most browsers support that unit and this is the answer when compatibility isn't an issue. For oldie IE, you are stuck with my method.