# Windows Chrome + Black Cross

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, resize

I'm wondering if anyone has any insight into this strange problem when running a very simple website in chrome on windows. I'm essentially stacking 5 divs on top of each other that I resize if the window resizes.

```
<body>
    <div id="home"></div>
    <div id="about"></div>
    <div id="experience"></div>
    <div id="hobbies"></div>
    <div id="contact"></div>
</body>
```

[Here is the code via media queries](http://jsfiddle.net/7myszjwc/)

[Here is the code via javascript/jquery](http://jsfiddle.net/4r0knkg4/)

Both versions should do identical things, I was simply trying to isolate the problem. On my Mac, everything seems to work fine bar some strange things that happen if I resize very rapidly. It works 100% on Firefox and Safari.

On my Windows PC, this happens seemingly at random on Chrome (IE works fine...):

[image: Weird cross]

When I'm resizing my site, this will randomly take over the screen, and if I don't resize or refresh, will stay as I scroll the page. If I resize or refresh it will disappear and be replaced with the properly colored divs. Also, on a tablet windows PC, chrome seems to lag like crazy with the media queries when resizing, though I'm not sure if that's related or not.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! It's bugging me like crazy.

EDIT: Here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27651878/chrome-and-media-queries-bug) to a previous question I asked that resolved one related issue.

Comment: working fine on my chrome

Comment: Seems to be fine in jsfiddle, if that's what you did. If I download the frame source that jsfiddle generates and run it locally, it bugs out and shows that upon resizing (randomly at different sizes). Chrome Version 39.0.2171.95 m

Comment: @Era Try to inspect element, replace the html from the whole page by the html inside the frame and resize it.

Comment: Same issue here, Chrome Version 39.0.2171.99 m

Comment: Solution/fix noted in the link at bottom to the prev question.